# Call a function for the number of items in a data frame and merge the results together

Tags: r, rjson

I have a function called getWeatherForMonth that takes a start date and end date and returns as data frame of the result for each month. I have another method getWeatherForRange that takes a data frame of ranges. I need to call getWeatherForMonth  for each row in the "dates" and combine the results into one data frame. I was using mapply like below but it's not combining the resulting data frames.

```
library(RJSONIO)

    getWeatherForMonth <- function(start.date, end.date) {
        url <- "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?key=PUT-YOUR-KEY-HERE&q=London&format=json&date=%s&enddate=%e&tp=24"
        url <- gsub("%s", start.date, url)
        url <- url <- gsub("%e", end.date, url)

        data <- fromJSON(url)
        weather <- data$data$weather
        GMT <- sapply(weather, function(x){as.character(x[1])})
        Max.TemperatureC <- sapply(weather, function(x){as.numeric(x[3])})
        Min.TemperatureC <- sapply(weather, function(x){as.numeric(x[4])})
        Wind.SpeedKm.h <- sapply(weather, function(x){as.numeric(x$hourly[[1]]$windspeedKmph[1])})
        Precipitationmm <- sapply(weather, function(x){as.numeric(x$hourly[[1]]$precipMM[1])})
        DewPointC <-sapply(weather, function(x){as.numeric(x$hourly[[1]]$DewPointC[1])}) 
        Wind.Chill <-sapply(weather, function(x){as.numeric(x$hourly[[1]]$WindChillC[1])}) 
        Cloud.Cover <-sapply(weather, function(x){as.numeric(x$hourly[[1]]$cloudcover[1])}) 
        Description <-sapply(weather, function(x){as.character(x$hourly[[1]]$weatherDesc[1])}) 
        Humidity <- sapply(weather, function(x){as.numeric(x$hourly[[1]]$humidity[1])}) 
        Feels.LikeC <- sapply(weather, function(x){as.numeric(x$hourly[[1]]$FeelsLikeC[1])})

        df <- data.frame(GMT, Max.TemperatureC, Min.TemperatureC, Wind.SpeedKm.h, Precipitationmm, DewPointC, Wind.Chill, Cloud.Cover, Description, Humidity, Feels.LikeC)

        return(df)
    }

    getWeatherForRange <- function(dates) {
        df <- mapply(getWeatherForMonth, dates$start.date, dates$end.date)

        return(df)
    }

    start.date <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), length=12, by="1 month")
    end.date <- seq(as.Date("2015-02-01"),length=12,by="months") - 1
    dates.2015 <- data.frame(start.date, end.date)

    data <- getWeatherForRange(dates)
    View(data)
```

The output looks like this
[Screenshot of the current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv1AA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `Map()`. Specifically, in your *getWeatherForRange* function, use `Map()` which is actually a wrapper for the non-simplified version of `mapply()`, equivalent to `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`. By default, `mapply()` returns a vector, matrix, or higher dimensional array. But you require a dataframe (i.e., a list object) return.

This updated function will return a list of dataframes that you can then later run a `do.call(rbind, ...)`, assuming all columns are consistent in each df, to stack all dfs together for a final dataframe.

```
getWeatherForRange <- function(dates) {
  # EQUIVALENT LINES
  dfList <- Map(getWeatherForMonth, dates$start.date, dates$end.date)
  # dfList <- mapply(getWeatherForMonth, dates$start.date, dates$end.date, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  return(dfList)
}

start.date <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), length=12, by="1 month")
end.date <- seq(as.Date("2015-02-01"), length=12, by="months") - 1
dates <- data.frame(start.date, end.date)

datalist <- getWeatherForRange(dates)         # DATAFRAME LIST
data <- do.call(rbind, datalist)              # FINAL DATA FRAME
```